# Confusion related to Big O

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

I was working on space and time complexity and came across this

O(n + (n/2 + n/4 .... n/n)) = O(n + log(n)).

I didn't get how this is true? Can anyone please provide some insights?

Comment: if you say n/2 + n/4 + n/6 + ... + n/n, there is some confusion.. because if n was (1, 3, 5, 7 etc...) you will never have n/n   :)

Comment: What's the pattern in the denominators? Is this 2, 4, 8, 16, ... or is it 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ... or something else?

Answer (score 7):

I think this depends on your denominators. The summation

> n + n / 2 + n / 4 + n / 8 + ... + n / n

sums out to O(n), since it's equal to

> n (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...)
>
> ≤ 2n

Therefore, it's technically correct that it's O(n + log n) because O(n + log n) = O(n), but that's a very strange way to write it. O(n) is a much better way to write this out.

The summation

> n + n/2 + n/4 + n/6 + n/8 + ... + n / n

works out to

> n (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/6 + 1/8 + ... + 1/n)
>
> = n (1 + (1/2) * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/6 + ... + 1/(n/2)))
>
> = n (1 + (1/2)H_{(n/2)})
>
> = Θ(n log n)

This works because the [nth harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) is Θ(log n). That's probably closer to what was intended, but with + replaced with ×.

Hope this helps!